# SQL Aggregate Queries

Tags: sql

Need to have query to have distinct item and sum of that item.

GroupBy works for me

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple SUM:

```
SELECT name, SUM(count)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name, sum(count)
From table
Group by name
```